# Infinite Loop in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

The seemingly simple regex command appears to put python into an infinite loop/hang:

```
import re
re.search(r"([A-Z]+\s*)+,", "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA ON BEHALF OF THE ENVIRONMENTAL")
```

I waited about 10 mins for the above command to complete, but it never did.  However, the line below completes after about 5 to 10 seconds on my machine:

```
re.search(r"([A-Z]+\s*)+,", "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA ON BEHALF")
```

So is this a python bug or is the particular regex written very inefficiently? If the problem is the latter, why is that so and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
re.search(r"([A-Z]+\s*)+", "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA ON BEHALF OF THE ENVIRONMENTAL")
```

remove the comma or escape it with a `\` if you want to do a literal match

Comment: It's already literal, backslashing it doesn't do anything.